# How can I use Weierstrass curve operations with a=-3 for implementing operations for a=0?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

I am working with golang's [elliptic library](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/elliptic/elliptic.go).

It implements functions on Weierstrass elliptic curves with $a=-3$. I need to make my own library that allows me to handle curves with $a=0$. I understand there are specific equations to use to optimally perform operations on different elliptic curves, which can be found in [Short Weierstrass curves](http://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw.html).

I would like to know which functions from the library I should change, and which stay the same (as I'm not an expert in cryptography). Here is the full list:

IsOnCurve, affineFromJacobian, Add, addJacobian, Double, doubleJacobian, ScalarMult, ScalarBaseMult, GenerateKey, Marshal, Unmarshal, and some initialization functions.

As I understand I need to change the following:

- IsOnCurve (removing the -3x)
- doubleJacobian (different equation)
- and the init functions

Those should stay the same:

- Add
- addJacobian (same optimal equation)
- Double
- ScalarBaseMult
- Marshal
- Unmarshal

And I'm not sure about those:

- affineFromJacobian
- ScalarMult
- GenerateKey

Can anyone tell me if my list is correct, and if not, give me some feedback on how I should change the given items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not thoroughly investigated golang's elliptic library (or Go at all), but I have implemented elliptic curves (with Jacobian coordinates) and I would say that your guess is correct. The "$a$" parameter is not used in the addition of two distinct points, but it appears in the formulas for doubling a point. With Jacobian coordinates, a normal implementation will include core functions such as `addJacobian()` and `doubleJacobian()`, which are used only through wrappers which filter out the special cases (if both operants to an "add" are identical, then it must be a "double"; if one operand is the point-at-infinity, then the result is the other operand).

The $a$ curve parameter is supposedly used when doubling a point, and when deciding if a point is on the curve or not (by applying the curve equation). It would also be used in point (de)compression, a kind of marshalling which saves a bit of space; but point compression does not appear to be implemented in the code you link to (it is optional and rumoured to be patented, which is why it is often avoided).

I am not entirely sure that the code is correct, though. In `ScalarMult()`, the multiplier is not reduced modulo the curve order, so an oversized value `k` could imply calling `addJacobian()` on a point and itself, something which does not appear to be handled in the code (this should be checked: if $n$ is the curve order, try $k = n+2$; this should yield $2G$ if the code is correct).